# Getters, constructors and eval

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm trying to parse an object generated from an Excel file. The output lists each cell with its contents. If the cell is just a number then it remains a number but if the cell contains a formula (has attribute `f`) I want to make that a getter so whenever that cell is called the result is updated in case the other cells change.

```
var Sheet = function Sheet(obj) {
    var i;
    for (i in obj){
        if (obj[i].f !== undefined){
            this['_'+i] = obj[i].f;

        } else {
            this[i] = obj[i].v;
        }       
    }
}

var SheetConstructor = function(obj){
    var new_sheet = new Sheet(obj);
    var getters = Object.keys(new_sheet).filter(
        function(attr){ 
            if (attr.charAt(0) === '_'){ 
                return attr
            }
        });

    for (g in getters){
        Object.defineProperty(new_sheet, getters[g].substring(1), { 
            get: function(){
                return eval(new_sheet[getters[g]]);
            } 
        });
    }
    return new_sheet;
}
```

Input object:

```
{ 
  B2: { t: 'n', v: 20, w: '20' },
  C2: { t: 'n', v: 115, w: '115' },
  B3: { t: 'n', v: 400, f: 'this.B2*20', w: '400' },
  C3: { t: 'n', v: 600, w: '600' },
  B5: { t: 'n', v: 20, w: '20' },
  D6: { t: 'n', v: 22, w: '22' },
  D7: { t: 'n', v: 36, w: '36' },
  B8:
   { t: 'n',
     v: 26.666666666666668,
     f: 'this.B2 * this.C2',
     w: '26.66666667' },
  D8: { t: 'n', v: 153, f: 'this.B5 + this.D6 + this.D7', w: '153' }
}
```

I know the security implications of `eval()` and am not worried about them in this case. This setup currently works but eventually I will have references across multiple sheets so I wanted some feedback on my solution.